# pygame.error: video system not initialized but I've typed pygame.init()

Tags: python, pygame, replit

I ran this code on replit.com, but this didn't work and said video system not initialized.
Can anyone tell me what I should do?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

while True:
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Add after `pygame.init()`  `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))` where 640, 480 are the size of the screen to create.

Comment: Check out https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/examples.htm

Answer (score -1):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

while True:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.update()
```

You need to define the display dimensions, try the code above.

Comment: You set the display mode within the `while True` loop again and again instead of once before starting the loop.